# Indices not working on sqlite table

Tags: ios, sqlite, indexing

I am using indices on columns on which I am making a search. The indices are created like this:

```
CREATE INDEX index1 on <TABLE>(<col1> COLLATE NOCASE ASC)
CREATE INDEX index2 on <TABLE>(<col2> COLLATE NOCASE ASC)
CREATE INDEX index3 on <TABLE>(<col3> COLLATE NOCASE ASC)
```

Now, the select query to search for records is like this:

```
select <col1> from <TABLE> where <col1> like '%monit%' AND <col2> like '%84%'   GROUP BY <col1> limit 0,501;
```

When I run EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN on my sqlite database like this:

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN select <col1> from <TABLE> where <col1> like '%monit%' AND <col2> like '%84%'   GROUP BY <col1> limit 0,501;
```

It returns the output as:

0|0|0|SCAN TABLE  USING INDEX  (~250000 rows)

and when I drop the index, the output this EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN produces is:

0|0|0|SCAN TABLE  (~250000 rows)
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY

Isn't the number of rows that are scanned (~250000 rows) were supposed to be lesser when index was used in searching the table???

I guess the problem here is with LIKE keyword, because I have read somewhere that LIKE keyword nullifies the use if indices... [Here is the link](http://web.utk.edu/~jplyon/sqlite/SQLite_optimization_FAQ.html)

EDIT: For indices to work on a query which is using LIKE, The right-hand side of the LIKE must be a string literal that does not begin with a wildcard character. So, in the above query, I tried using search parameter in like without '%' at the beginning:

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN select <col1> from <TABLE> where <col1> like 'monit%' AND <col2> like '84%'   GROUP BY <col1> limit 0,501;
```

and the output I got was this:

0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE partnumber USING INDEX model_index_partnumber (model>? AND model

so,you see. The number of rows being searched (rather than scan) are (~15625 rows) in this.
But the problem now is I cannot do away with % wild card at the beginning. Anyone pls suggest me an alternative way to achieve the same....

EDIT:
I have tried using FTS3 from terminal but when I typed this query:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE <tbl> USING FTS3 (<col_list>);
```

Its throwing error as:
Error: no such module: FTS3

Someone pls help me to enable FTS3 from terminal as well as XCode (need the steps I must perform for both tasks).

I am using sqlcipher and have already perform this from terminal:

```
CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1" ./configure
```

EDIT:

Please visit the question [sqlite table taking time to fetch the records in LIKE query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596099/sqlite-table-taking-time-to-fetch-the-records-in-like-query) posted by me

EDIT:

Hey All, I got some success. I modified my select query to look like this:

```
select distinct description collate nocase as description from partnumber where rowid BETWEEN 1 AND (select max(rowid) from partnumber) AND description like '%a%' order by description;
```

And Bingo, the search time was like never before. But the problem now is when I execute the command EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN like this, it shows me using B-Tree for distinct which I dont want to use.

```
explain query plan select distinct description collate nocase as description from partnumber where rowid BETWEEN 1 AND (select max(rowid) from partnumber) AND description like '%a%' order by description;
```

Output:

```
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE partnumber USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid>? AND rowid<?) (~15625 rows)
0|0|0|EXECUTE SCALAR SUBQUERY 1
1|0|0|SEARCH TABLE partnumber USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (~1 rows)
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT
```

Answer (score 3):

A couple other options ...

Full Text Indexes:

http://sqlite.org/fts3.html

> The most common (and effective) way to describe full-text searches is
>   "what Google, Yahoo and Altavista do with documents placed on the
>   World Wide Web".

```
SELECT count(*) FROM enrondata1 WHERE content MATCH 'linux';  /* 0.03 seconds */
SELECT count(*) FROM enrondata2 WHERE content LIKE '%linux%'; /* 22.5 seconds */
```

Word Breaking:

If you're looking for words (or words that start with), you can break text blobs into words yourself and store your own indexed word tables.  But even then, you'll be able to only do word like 'monit%' to get hits like "monitor"

If possible, use the full text - it will be much less code.  But, if that's not an option for some reason, then you can fall back to your own word breaking tables but that's limited words begins with to avoid scans.  (better than whole text block begins with).

Be aware that the sqlite that comes with iOS does not have Full Text enabled.  You can work around that.  There's instructions on that and it's use at:

http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/06/16/sqlite-full-text-search-for-iphone-ipadyour-own-sqlite-for-iphone-and-ipad/

The full docs on creating and querying full text tables are here:  http://sqlite.org/fts3.html

To get FTS3 to also work from terminal, see:

Compiling the command line interface @ http://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html

[sqlite3 using fts3 create table in my mac terminal and how to use it in iphone xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939592/sqlite3-using-fts3-create-table-in-my-mac-terminal-and-how-to-use-it-in-iphone-x)

Comment: Hey bryanmac, to use FTS3, I will have to create tables using CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE <> USING .... query instead of CREATE TABLE <>..... query?? Also, if I want to search records containing '%moni%', then will I need to use MATCH 'moni' instead of LIKE '%moni%???'

Answer (score 2):

This is quite simple. You are telling SQLITE to examine every record in the table. It is faster to do this without using an index, because using an index wuld involve additional IO. And index is used when you want to examine a subset of the records in a table where the extra IO of using the index is paid back by not having to examine every record in the table.

When you say *LIKE* "%something" that means `all records with anything at all at the beginning of the field, followed by something`. The only way to do this is to examine every single record. Note that indexes should still be used if you only use *LIKE* "something%" because in this case, SQLITE can use the index to find the subset of records beginning with "something". In the old days when databases where not so clever we used to write it like this to enforce the use of an index. `SELECT * WHERE col1 >= "something" AND col1 < "somethinh"`, Note the intentional mispelling of something in the second condition.

If you can it is best to avoid using `%` at the beginning of a LIKE condition. In some cases you may be able to change your schema so that data is stored in two columns rather than one. Then you use a *LIKE* "something%" search on the second of the two columns. Of course this depends on your data being structured right.

But even if splitting into two columns is not possible, it may be possible to divide and conquer the data in another way. For instance you could split the search fields into words, and index every word in a single column in another search table. That way "look for something or other" becomes a list of records where "something" is an exact match on a record in the search table. No LIKE required. You would then get a record ID to retrieve the original record. This is one of the things that SOLR does internally so if you must stick with SQLITE and cannot leverage SOLR or LUCENE in any way, then you can always read up on how they build inverted indices and do the same thing yourself in your SQLITE db.

Remember that *LIKE* "%something%" must examine every record, but if you can select a subset of the data first, and then apply the *LIKE* search, this will run a lot faster. Filling the cache will have the same effect which is what your experiments with DISTINCT were doing. Maybe all you need to do is to enlarge the cache to get acceptable search times. The first search will still be slow, but people are often quite forgiving of problems which go away when you retry it.

When you use arbitrary wildcards like that you are getting very close to a full text search engine requirement like SOLR. These work by indexing the data 100% in RAM. With SQLITE you might be able to do something similar by creating a second in-memory database, reading all data from the disk tables into the in-memory db, then using the in-memory db for searching with wildcards. You would still have full-table scans with queries such as `LIKE "%monit%"` however that scan takes place in RAM where it is not as timeconsuming. You don't need to import all your data into RAM, only the parts where you need "%something%" searches, because SQLITE can do cross-database joins. SQLITE makes it easy to create an in-memory database, and the `ATTACH DATABASE` and `DETACH DATABASE` commands make it easy to connect a second database to your app. There is some example code for IOS in this question [Can iPhone sqlite apps attach to other databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376912/can-iphone-sqlite-apps-attach-to-other-databases)

Not sure why you don't like EXPLAIN using B-Trees since the b-tree is probably the fastest possible search structure available when your data has to be read from a filesystem.

Comment: Thanks Michael. But the problem is I dont have only 1 table in my db. There are at least 10 tables. Although other table contains only 1K or 2K records, but storing them in RAM will affect my device memory (iPhone or iPad). If you are suggesting to store only this one particular table in RAM, then I really dont know how to store 1 table in RAM and other 10 in Memory. If you have any alternative solution, then I will try that. I have edited the question again. Just have a loot at the link.

Answer (score 1):

I have a MySQL book that suggests `REVERSE()` the text (and if your application permits, store in a column). Then search the reversed text using `LIKE(REVERSE('%something'))`.

Comment: Hey Poodlehat, I can not do that because I am applying LIKE on 3 cols simultaneously in some of the queries. So reversing the text and then applying like won't help. Besides I want to search for values that contains search term at any position.